# Unescaped link text for html.actionlink

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following line of code that "in theory" should display a button with the text "Cart (0)" where 0 is the number of items in the cart.  HOWEVER Microsoft and their infamous wisdom can't make something work the way one would expect it to.  They so graciously escape the HTML for me so I end up with this as my button text "Cart (<span id='#itemsInCart'></span>)".  I've tried using Html.Raw as a wrapper for the text but that produced the same results.  Really frustrated with MS and their "making life easier" for you approach.  Sorry, I'm just very frustrated at fighting with this "technology".  Calgon take me back to PHP land where things actually make sense.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cart (&lt;span id='#itemsInCart'&gt;&lt;/span&gt;)", "Index", "Cart", vbNull, New With {.class = "MainMenuButton"})
```

Anybody know how to produce the results I'm looking for or point me to a good tutorial (other than microsoft documentation) on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Cart", vbNull)" class="MainMenuButton">
    Whatever you want</a>
```

Comment: Awesome! I had to step away I was so frustrated I couldn't put that together.  And the sad thing is I've used @Url.Action before.  smh in shame.  Thank you for your response.  I'd give it an up arrow if I could.

Comment: Thanks TrueBlueAussie.  : )